# Unit Test Duo Security "Duo Verify"

Tags: node.js

We are using the duo_web sdk for nodejs to implement 2FA into our backend. We have an initial login endpoint that makes the sign_request and this portion is working as expected and unit testable. It also returns a token for the user logging in.

The second portion involves the sign_response from duo. When the sign_request goes to the front end, the duo iframe is initialized with that sign_request. The response from this iframe is a sign_response that is then sent to the backend with the authorization token. The sign_response is sent to duo via the duo.verify_response function on the duo_web sdk.

The problem here arises when unit testing. There isn't a mock sdk for DUO for me to work with (as there is with something like the aws sdk) and there isn't a way from the backend to generate a sign_response. I was tempted to use something like nock to mock the http call, but the duo sdk is built on top of websockets.

If anyone has experience with this and can help it would be greatly appreciated. I'll try and clarify anything that's unclear.

For Reference here is the sdk: https://www.npmjs.com/package/duo_web